# Aphanumeric sender ID on trial account

Tags: twilio

Does alphanumeric sender ID work on trial account?
I try to send sms using powerautomate and when i enter custom value into twilio send ssms action i get error The 'From' number  is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.

Answer (score 1):

You require an upgraded account to send messages with an alphanumeric sender ID on Twilio. Check the [limitations of alphanumeric sender IDs here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS#h_01F4SK0DVD49N6BTMRX78RAZNE) for details.

Comment: It says I can use an E.164 format?  I tried +447NNNNNNNNNN (UK mobile number), but it wouldn't recognise this.

Comment: Is this comment related to the original question (trial and alpha numeric senders)? If not, please open a new question.